# Sending data over the PS/2 port

Tags: embedded, mouse, arm, lpc, ps2

I'm writing a mouse driver from scratch for an LPC2148 and I'm stuck on this point.  I can receive data from a keyboard but mice require command codes to be sent to it.  Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: I suggest that there is no "best way to do this", but rather "one way". You question rather suggests that you know a way, but think there is a better way.  What is your question *exactly*?

Answer (score 0):

The information is widely available:

- [PS/2 Mouse Interfacing - Computer-Engineering.org](http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2mouse/)
- [The PS/2 Mouse - Centrum voor Wiskunde en Informatica](http://www.scs.stanford.edu/11wi-cs140/pintos/specs/kbd/scancodes-12.html)
- [PS/2 Mouse Commands - OSDev Wiki](http://wiki.osdev.org/Mouse_Input#PS2_Mouse_Commands)
- [PS/2 Commands - Altuim](http://wiki.altium.com/display/ADOH/PS2+Commands)

[This resource](http://www.computer-engineering.org/ps2keyboard/) from Computer-Engineering.org describes the PS/2 interface in detail. Both keyboard and mouse controllers have output *and* input ports.  You can send commands to the keyboard as well as the mouse.  The page includes PIC assembler code example of writing to the keyboard, writing to the mouse is done in the same way.